# How do I Extend the Silverlight TabControl for DataBinding?

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol, extensibility

[Yi-Lun Luo at Microsoft says:](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/18256/275257.aspx#61933)

> [C]urrently [the] TabControl doesn't override
>   PrepareContainerForItemOverride, so it
>   won't automatically wrap your data
>   source in TabItems.

So the question is: How do I create my own control that:

1. Extends the TabControl.
2. Overrides the PrepareContainerForItemOverride.
3. Automatically wraps my data source in TabItems or my own TabItemExtended controls?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a good example of a [subclassed TabControl](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/26112#494574) is the Prism RI.  Make sure to look at Themes\generic.xaml and Shell.xaml for the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the custom class which is derived from the Silverlight TabControl class.
It supports data binding and works correctly with the ObservableCollection class.
In my implementation I added the `ItemsSource` property with several other properties and handled changes of the source collection.

Here is the link: http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-data-binding/